# Average on Array

Tags: c++, c

I have been struggling with this problem and that is why I am asking here for help.

Let's imagine the following set of values for an array called "scores"

```
20 30 40 50 10 20 40 10
```

What I want to do is to create a loop that calculates the average each 4 values . In this case and doing manual math it should be

```
(20+30+40+50)/4
(10+20+40+10)/4
```

Now , my point and my problem is that I do not know how to do that with a single loop. I understand that I can setup two loops and then do so , but as obvious if the array were bigger then I would have to setup hundreds of loops.Right now the solution I made is very far from the real solution

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string names[4] = {"Peter","Mark","July","Sarah"};
  double scores [16] = {20,30,100,60,30,40,10,90,10,99,100,12,100,100,10,100};
  double average[4] ;
  int i;

    for (int d = 0, i = 0; d < 4 - 1; d++)
    {
        average[i] += scores[d];
        if (d % 4 == 0) {
            average[i] /= 4;
            i++;
        }
    }

    for (int l = 0 ; l < 4 ; l++)
    {

        cout << "\nName : " << names[l] << endl << endl ;
        cout << "Average :  " << average[l] << endl;

    }

}
```

Desired Output :

Name : Peter 
Average : 52.5 
Name : Mark 
Average : 42.5 
Name : July 
Average : 55.25
Name : Sarah
Average : 77.5

Actual Output : 
Name : Peter 
Average : 5 
Name : Mark 
Average : 130 
Name : July 
Average : 3.11076e-317 
Name : Sarah
Average : 6.90921e-310

Comment: hint: you can increase d by more than 1 on each iteration of the loop

Comment: Why hundreds of loops? It would always be two loops, the outer one over the students and the inner one over each student's scores (what ever way the data is physically organized -- these two indices are always needed to access a specific score for a specific student). Each of the loops may be *iterated* arbitrarily often, but that's logically different. So this is an argument for using nested loops, explicitly or implicitly as via accumulate.

Comment: So, is this a C or a C++ question? Or are you restricted to the intersection?

Comment: I added more details and an example code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to use the basics of c++. The following code will give you the output you want.

```
      string names[4] = {"Peter","Mark","July","Sarah"};
      double scores [16] = {20,30,100,60,30,40,10,90,10,99,100,12,100,100,10,100};
      double average[4] ;
      int i;

        for (int d = 1, i = 0; d <= 16; d++)
        {
            average[i] += scores[d-1];
            if (d % 4 == 0) {
                average[i] /= 4;
                i++;
            }
        }

        for (int l = 0 ; l < 4 ; l++)
        {

            cout << "\nName : " << names[l] << endl << endl ;
            cout << "Average :  " << average[l] << endl;

        }
```

Comment: I have edited the code and checked the code. This will work for sure.

Comment: Take a look at the example I posted with your solution and the results obtained vs desired

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I understand your input data, and your goal, I believe something simple like this should work:

```
for (int i=0; i < num_students; i++)
    average[i] = std::accumulate(scores + 4*i, scores + 4*i + 4, 0) / 4;
```

Comment: I never covered accumulate on classes...thanks for your help but I cannot use that for this exercise

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
average[0] = 0;
average[1] = 0;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < scores_students; ++i)
{
  average[0] += scores[0 + i];
  average[1] += scores[4 + i];
}
average[0] = average[0] / scores_students;
average[1] = average[1] / scores_students;
```

Note that `scores[0 + i]` uses the scores in the first set of 4.
Also `scores[4 + i]` uses scores in the second set of 4.

Comment: This works..but If the array were bigger I would have to make more  average[x] and know how much I have to add to i . Right?

Comment: If you were to have more averages, you would use more than one `for` loop, but your requirement is restricted to one `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is the first thing that crossed my mind.

```
   #include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string names[4] = {"Peter","Mark","July","Sarah"};
    double scores[16] = {20,30,100,60,30,40,10,90,10,99,100,12,100,100,10,100};
    double average[4];
    for(int i = 0; i < 16 + 1; i+=4)
    {
        if(i != 0 && i % 4 == 0)
            average[(i / 4)-1] = (scores[i-4]+scores[i-3]+scores[i-2]+scores[i-1]) / 4;
    }
    for (int l = 0 ; l < 4 ; l++)
    {

        cout << "\nName : " << names[l] << endl << endl ;
        cout << "Average :  " << average[l] << endl;

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why not use `i+=4` in the for loop?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your problem, your main goal is just creating the speediest code. You want to have only one loop w/o any if statement.

My solution #1:

```
int scores[] = {20,30,100,60,30,40,10,90,10,99,100,12,100,100,10,100};
double avgs[4] = {};

for (int it = 0; it < 16; ++it)
{
    avgs[it / 4] += scores[it] / 4.0;
}

for (int it = 0; it < 4; ++it)
{
    cout << it << ": " << avgs[it] << endl;
}
```

My solution #2:

```
double accumulate(int input[4])
{
    return (input[0] + input[1] + input[2] + input[3]) / 4.0;
}

for (int it = 0; it < 4; ++it)
{
    avgs[it] = accumulate(scores + 4 * it);
}
```